# How to solve VSCode stuck on 'Installing extension'?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

With my extension on VSCode, the Extensions tab is permanetently shown with the working/timer icon. Three extensions are shown to be installing when open up VSCode, and installing any other extension gets stuck in the same state. Nothing else happens from here, there is a large RAM and CPU usage at all times, larger than I remember, but nothing will change state over time. The extension tab itself takes several minutes to generate what is already installed.

I have tried clearing extensions cache in AppData, I have re-installed, force closed, no change in behaviour. It's not coming from anti-virus blocking or poor internet either. Sometimes removing an extension shows as complete but I have to close and re-open VSCode window to see that. Installing manually with .mvse doesn't change anything either. This does not apply to anything stuck in installing state. Checking logs of VSCode, I cannot see any immediate errors, the installation log just slowly ticks over as follows, when left alone:

[info] Getting Manifest... wallabyjs.quokka-vscode

[info] Installing extension: wallabyjs.quokka-vscode

[info] Extension signature is verified: wallabyjs.quokka-vscode

[info] Getting Manifest... wallabyjs.quokka-vscode

[info] Extensions is already requested to install wallabyjs.quokka-vscode

Closing VSCode now just goes back to state before any installation attempts

Note: This is not unique to trying to install Quokka

Thanks!